# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\sin^{n}x (1-\sin x)^2 dx$ using a convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\sin^{n}x (1-\sin x)^2 dx$$

Let $g_n = \sin^{n}x (1-\sin x)^2$

$g_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $g_n \ge 0$ so applying the Beppo Levi Theorem we get -

$$= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin^{n}x (1-\sin x)^2 dx$$

$$= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}(1-\sin x)^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin^{n}x dx$$

Now $\sin^{n}x < 1$ for $x \in (\pi/4, \pi/3)$ so we have a geometric series and hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin^{n}x = \frac{1}{1 - \sin x}$$

This gives us -

$$= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}(1-\sin x)^2 \frac{1}{1 - \sin x} dx$$

$$= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}(1-\sin x)dx$$

$$= x + \cos  x \mid_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}$$

$$\frac{\pi}{3} + \cos \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Is this correct? In particular, have I got the correct conditions to apply the Beppo Levi Theorem?

Comment: your usage of this lemma is ok

Answer (score 1):

The use of Beppo-Levi's theorem and the computations are correct.